# Rstudio not showing the Rcpp code completion or error highlightling

Tags: autocomplete, rstudio, rcpp

This is the output of version in Rstudio

```
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.1                         
year           2015                        
month          06                          
day            18                          
svn rev        68531                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
nickname       World-Famous Astronaut
```

I think this version should support the auto completion for Rcpp. In my global settings also I had make sure that auto completion will work. What is the problem? Please help me. I have installed the Rstudio from the repository as described in docs using YUM.

Comment: I have tried installing previous version of Rstudio 0.98 one . Still facing the same issue. I am using centos 7

Comment: This usually happens to me with unsaved documents (CentOS 7 also) - are you having this problem even with saved documents? Also, installing clang might solve the problem ( `yum install clang`), as some Linux distributions (e.g. CentOS) only have GCC by default.

Comment: @nrussell But RStudio ships 'sumo-style' with everything it needs in its tarball.

Comment: @srinath: Use a current version of RStudio.  May as well [start with the dailies](https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/) which work great for me -- on Ubuntu -- as both desktop and server versions.

Comment: @nrussell and when I said tarball I meant deb or rpm file :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel "But RStudio ships 'sumo-style'" - yes my mistake; I had a similar issue shortly after the release of 0.99.441 and RStudio support instructed me to install clang, but it looks like that was fixed in the [99.442](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200716783-RStudio-Release-History) release.

Comment: Thank you so much nrussell and Sir Dirk Eddelbuettel. Unfortunately i am on a vacation and i dont have laptop with me. As soon as i get my laptop i will use your techniques. It is so great that legend of Rcpp , Sir Dirk Eddelbuettel is answering my pityful question. Sir i am a fan of yours. The rcpp work you have done is mind blowing!! Thank you very much.

Comment: @nrussell , Sir i was facing the issue even after saving the doc. I will use your suggestion of installing the Clang and will let you know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you @nrussell . By installing the clang and then reinstalling the rstudio , solved the problem. I am unable to mark the your solution as an answer. Thank you a lot.

Comment: add the same problem on Fedora 21 and lattest 0.99.489 Rsudio, installing clang `dnf install clang` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @nrussell installing the clang worked. I reinstalled the rstudio after that and things are very ok. Thank you @nrussell and @Dirk EddellBuettel